# SSRS - tooltip displays "report chart" even when the Tooltip property is empty

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

In Reporting Services 2016, when hovering over a chart it always displays a "Report chart" tooltip. The actual Tooltip property is empty. It happens in both IE and Chrome. Is there a way to disable the Tooltip when is empty?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting a space for the tooltip?

Comment: Yes, but the tooltip is still showing empty

Answer (score 0):

In a tooltip field in SSRS you need to cast a number as a string using the CStr() function for it to be displayed.

For example, in the tooltip, specify something like:

```
=CStr(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value))
```

If dealing with a null value you should test for Nothing and not an empty string.

This means a test something like this:

```
=Switch(Nothing, "", true, CStr(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ToolTip expression to the below code to remove "Report Chart" display:

```
=" "
```